# regex c# optional group - should act greedy?

Tags: c#, regex, option-type, greedy, regex-group

having regex ~like this:

```
blablabla.+?(?:<a href="(http://.+?)" target="_blank">)?
```

I want to capture an url if I find one... finds stuff but I don't get the link (capture is always empty). Now if I remove the question mark at the end like this

```
blablabla.+?(?:<a href="(http://.+?)" target="_blank">)
```

This will only match stuff that has the link at the end... it's 2.40 am... and I've got no ideas...

--Edit--

sample input:

`blablabla    asd 1234t535    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">`

expected output:

`match 0:`

```
    group 1: <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
    group 2: http://google.com`
```

I just want "http://google.com" or ""

Comment: And what happens if you add `.*` at the end of the last one?

Comment: what is the purpose of "blablabla.+?"

Comment: it would be good if you could provide some sample input and expected output.

Comment: @amcashcow  match SOMETHING then STUFF until you find a link

Comment: @markijbema no sorry, didn't - false alarm

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a whole-string match?  If so, try adding `.*` to the end of the first regex and see what it matches.  The problem with the first regex is that it can match anything after `blablabla` because of the `.+?` (leading to an empty capture), but the parenthesized part still won't match an `a` tag unless it's at the end of the string.  By the way, looking at your expected output, capture 1 will be the URL; the parentheses around the whole HTML tag are non-capturing because of the `?:` at the beginning.

Comment: but .+? should act as non greedy == stop on <a href=

Comment: @argh: Yes, it will, if the rest of the string matches `<a href ...`, but that requires the whole remainder of the string to be the tag.

Comment: HAH! GOT IT! Thanks Jeremiah - you lead me into solution: blablabla.+?<a href=(?:"(http://.+?)" target="_blank">)

Comment: @argh: What was the benefit of moving that parenthesized group?

Comment: Yeah... well... it worked for a second but only because there was a link later that didn't have the target="_blank" tag... ah... I was so happy for a second there...

Comment: @argh: Try the `.*` thing suggested earlier; that should fix the problem, unless the tags don't match the regex you gave.  BTW, are you going to have multiple links in the input text?  How are you planning to iterate through them?

Comment: Tried that .* - still no luck... and I'm fine with 1 link per page - for most of the pages there is only 1 link that interests me and it's the one going _out_ of the site

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't need .+? at the start, the regex is going to search the whole input anyway

you also have the closing '>' right after blank which will limit your matches

```
(?:<a href="(http://.+?)" target="_blank".*?>)
```

[regex test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%3ca+href%3d%22%28http%3a%2f%2f.%2b%3f%29%22+target%3d%22_blank%22.%2a%3f%3e%29&i=blablabla+asd+1234t535+%3ca+href%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com%22+target%3d%22_blank%22+%3e)

Comment: ok, sorry my sample is not quite precise... I need this blablabla in front - basically I need to extract url's to other sites from a baldy formed HTML... so they do something like: Name of the company `shitty unclosed html tags` <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"

Comment: well you can put whatever you want in front of it, but there is no need unless you want to restrict which urls match. and if you do that be as specific as possible

Comment: yep, and this is exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

It's the trailing ? that's doing you in.  Reason:  By marking it as optional, you're allowing the .+? to grab it.

```
blablabla.*(?:<a href="((http://)?.*)".+target="_blank".*>)
```

I modified it slightly... `.+?` is basically the same as `.*`, and if you may have nothing in your href (you indicated you wanted ""), you need to make the http optional as well as the trailing text.  Also, `.*` in front `target` means you have at least one space or character, but may have more (multiple blanks or other attributes).  `.*` before the `>` means you can have blanks or other attributes trailing after.

This will not match a line at all if there's no `<a href...>`, but that's what you want, right?

The `(?: ... )` can be dropped completely, if you don't need to capture the whole `<a href...>` portion.

This will fail if the attributes are not listed in the order specified... which is one of the reasons regex can't really be used to parse html.  But if you're certain the href will always come before the target, this should do what you need.

Comment: "This will not match a line at all if there's no <a href...>, but that's what you want, right?" --> No. We need a positive match with an empty capture group in such case.