# Prevent non-greedy part from consuming the following optional part

Tags: java, regex, non-greedy

I have a regex with a mandatory part, a non-greedy (lazy?) part, an optional part and finally another non-greedy part.

`<mandatory><non-greedy><optional><non-greedy>`
Implemented as:
`^mandatory.*?(:?optionalpart)?.*?$`

The optionalpart consists of 'a piece to find' and 'a piece to return in a capture group'.

`^mandatory.*?(:?findme(matchme))?.*?$`

But for some inputs the first non-greedy part consumes characters that the following optional part should match. Is there a way to make the optional part more greedy than the previous non-greedy part?

---

Example: Find the character after the `2,`, or find an empty string if there is no `2,` but the mandatory part matches.

```
"Foo: 2,b,1,a,3,c" -> match, $1 = "b"
"Foo: 1,a,2,b,3,c" -> match, $1 = "b"
"Foo: 1,a,3,c,2,b" -> match, $1 = "b"
"Foo: 2,b"         -> match, $1 = "b"
"Foo: 1,a,3,c"     -> match, $1 = ""
"Fuu: 1,a,2,b,3,c" -> no match.
```

Attempt 1: `^Foo: .*?(?:2,([a-z]))?.*?$`
This fails on the 2nd and 3rd example, returning `""` instead of `"2"`.

Attempt 2: `^Foo: .*?(?:2,([a-z])).*?$`
This fixes the previous fails, but now fails on the 5th example, not matching.
The part that must be optional is no longer optional.

<sub>If it matters, I'm using Java's Pattern class.</sub>

--

This was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214940/regex-c-sharp-optional-group-should-act-greedy), but there was no satisfactory answer for either of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regex is very close, you need to move `(?:` a bit more to the left to include the `.*?` pattern:

```
^Foo:(?: .*?2,([a-z]))?.*$
     ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mkjbns/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `Foo:` - some literal text
- `(?: .*?2,([a-z]))?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches *greedily* (will be tried at least once) 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `.*?` - space followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `2,` - a literal substring
  - `([a-z])` - Group 1: a lowercase letter
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars (the rest of the string)
- `$` - end of string.

The general pattern will look like

```
^<MANADATORY_LITERAL>(?:<NON_GREEDY_DOT>(<OPTIONAL_PART>))?<GREEDY_DOT>$
```

Comment: And then you added explanation. So the optional group is *greedy*. In that case, why didn't it take priority over the previous non-greedy part in my attempt 1?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Your `^Foo: .*?(?:2,([a-z]))?.*?$` did not work because after `Foo:` with space gets matched, `.*?` matches nothing (empty text), then `(?:2,([a-z]))?` matches nothing (empty text) - NOTE it would match some text *if* this group pattern immediately followed the space as it does with your String 1) - and then the last `.*?$` grabs the whole line.